# printing multiple fields from a database table in a drop down for selection

Tags: php, mysql, database, drop-down-menu

I currently have code which is producing a drop down with fields saved within the database table 'sueprvisor', however it is only show the variable 'E_number' when i need it to print out the corresponding supervisors 'Forename' and 'Surname' within the drop down as well? any one any idea where i am going wrong?

```
<?php

$dbQuery2 = $db->prepare("select E_number, Forename, Surname from supervisor");
$dbQuery2->execute();
echo"<select name='E_number'>";
echo"<option value='' name='E_number'></option>";
while($row=$dbQuery2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo "<option value='".$row['E_number']."'>".$row['E_number']."    </option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

Comment: This is the correct code to print out Enumber, Forename and Surname :)         <?php

$dbQuery2 = $db->prepare("select E_number, Forename, Surname from supervisor");
$dbQuery2->execute();
echo"<select name='E_number'>";
echo"<option value='' name='E_number'></option>";
while($row=$dbQuery2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo "<option value='".$row['E_number']."'>".$row['E_number']."".$row['Forename']."".$row['Surname']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>

Answer (score 0):

You are only asking for "E_number". Try using the subscript for the values you want:

```
echo "<option value='".$row['Surname']."'>".$row['Forename']."    </option>";
```

Comment: unfortunately this is only printing out the forename :( Im wondering if i need to do seperate querys and use $row1 $row2 $row3 etc... :S

Comment: No, you just need to put it together the way you want it. The data is in the $row array. You are looping through each row. You just need to get the data you want in the output you want. To test that try putting print_r($row); in place of the echo statement. You will see you have an array that includes: E_number, Forename, Surname because you are asking the database for those fields.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

`echo "<option value='".$row['E_number']."'>".$row['Forenname']." ".$row['Surname']."</option>";`

Comment: unfortunately this only prints out the surnames, not the enumber and forename and surname :(

Comment: `echo "<option value='".$row['E_number']."'>".$row['E_number']." ".$row['Forenname']." ".$row['Surname']."</option>";`